# PCs locked after a few minutes

Tags: windows-xp

I have a strange issue started happening. A few PCs on my network automatically gets locked after a few minutes in inactivity. These machines are part of a domain. This never happened before. I checked the local settings on the machines and specifically set then not to lock, but same thing keeps hapenning. Where else can I investigate this?

Comment: Did you check the screen saver settings?

Answer (score 4):

On an problem PC, open a CMD window and type the following:

`GPRESULT /z > gpresult.txt`

Open the txt file, and search for the word "screensaver".  If it's being set via Group Policy, you will be able to tell from this, and you'll also know which GPO is setting it.

You could use the RSOP MMC snapin, but I find this method to be much faster and the `/z` is super-verbose.

Comment: +1 for this, this sounds an awful like a GPO taking priority over whatever settings you're trying to use locally.